# Oracle SubStr for Description field

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I need help with the following Scenario.

There is a table with Company_Cd, Company_Name and All I need is the first 2 words of from the Company name if it has more than 3 words and 1 word if it has 2 words

Example:

```
Company_Cd     Company_Name
123            ABC SOLUTIONS INC
345            XYZ GLOBAL TECH SOLUTIONS
899            NOWHERE COMPANY INC LTD
654            QSW SOLUTIONS
```

Desired Output:

```
Company_Cd     Company_Name
123            ABC SOLUTIONS
345            XYZ GLOBAL
899            NOWHERE COMPANY
654            QSW
```

Comment: I tried using instr with substr function. but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: Show what you tried (edit it into the question) so people can explain why it's not working and help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Regular Expression:

```
SELECT Company_Cd,
       regexp_replace(company_name,'(((\w+)\s){'||CASE WHEN regexp_count(trim(company_name),' ') IN (0,1) THEN 1
                                                       ELSE 2
                                                       END||'}).*','\1' )
FROM   customer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the instr function to find the 1st and 2nd occurence of space and then use substr accordingly:

```
SELECT c.company_name,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN instr(c.company_name,' ',1,2) >0    THEN SUBSTR(c.company_name, 1, instr(c.company_name,' ',1,2))
    WHEN instr(c.company_name,' ',1,2) =0    AND instr(c.company_name,' ',1,1)  >0     THEN SUBSTR(c.company_name, 1, instr(c.company_name,' ',1,1))
    ELSE c.company_name
  END)
FROM customer c
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find below query for your use:

```
  SELECT Company_Cd, IF((length(Company_Name) - length(replace(Company_Name, ' ', '')) + 1) >= 3, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Company_Name, ' ', 2), IF((length(Company_Name) - length(replace(Company_Name, ' ', '')) + 1) >= 2, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Company_Name, ' ', 1), Company_Name)) as result FROM company LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Am getting the syntax Error

Comment: There is no "IF" in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select company_cd, 
       trim(substr(company_name, 1, instr(company_name || '  ', ' ', 1, 2) - 1)) 
from   company_tbl;
```

This solution begins by adding two spaces at the end of company_name; then it finds the position of the second space in this extended string, it removes the second space and everything after it - and then it trims the remaining space at the end (only needed if the company name was a single word; if all company names were guaranteed to be at least two words, the solution would be even simpler).